# Visa needed for the wife of a British citizen to live together in Spain

Tags: visas, spain

What visa would my wife need to live semi-permanently with me if we bought a property in Spain? She has been unable to get a job that matches the UK requirement of a job or threshold of 18K+. Will she be able to live in Spain indefinitely, if she remains a housewife?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Neil. This site is for short term travel, like vacations. We have a whole other site for moving and living abroad, called [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com). Your question will be a much better fit there, and we will ty to move it there as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Until Brexit, you can live and work in Spain and bring your immediate family with you. The only requirements are *your* citizenship and a genuine marriage.

Nobody knows how the Brexit will handle cases like yours if there *is* a treaty and not a hard Brexit.

Comment: Even with a hard brexit, Spain is likely to have an easier regime for spouses of British citizens with means than Britain currently does.

Comment: @phoog, I expect the EU will insist on reciprocity, and it is totally unclear what the *two* sides will be willing to concede to each other, especially since immigration was a hot button issue for Brexit.

Comment: Reciprocity with the EU has no bearing on Spain's requirements for third-country nationals to move to Spain as "economically inactive."  I believe that these are already less stringent than the UK criteria for a spouse of a British citizen.  Spain is unlikely to change that since such people are important to its economy.